# You are the first person [to notice the mistake]. (complement vs adjunct/modifier)

Tags: x-bar-theory

> You are the {first person to notice the mistake}.

There's no doubt {} is N'. The question is whether *first person* is a small N' on its own.

If *to notice the mistake* is an adjunct of *first person*, the to-infinitival should be a sister to N'(*first person*) and a daughter of {N'}. Then, *first person* must be N' on its own.

But if it's complement licensed by *first*, which I suspect it is, the to-infinitival should be a sister to N (*person*) and a daughter of {N'}.

---

In case you're not too familiar with or fond of X-bar theory, you still could answer the question. Instead of telling me whether or not *first person* is N', you could tell me whether or not *to notice the mistake* is a complement or adjunct/modifier of *first person*. And if it is complement, please also tell me if this is a case where a relative clause is not an adjunct/modifier but complement of its antecedent.

Comment: In my view, such cases involve a discontinuity inside the noun phrase. The adjective _first_ is indeed licensing the _to_-phrase, as you point out. I would therefore address such data in terms of extraposition within the noun phrase. Further evidence for extraposition within noun phrases is seen in examples like _A faster player than Peter was there_, where it is clear that _faster_ licenses _than Peter_.

Comment: @TimOsborne So you don't think _first person_ is N'?

Comment: I do not think much of X-bar analyses to begin with; they are too complex, i.e. too layered. But I think your question is good insofar as you are pointing to a problem that most analyses face, be they X-bar analyses or otherwise. Certainly most analyses view the adjective as a dependent of the noun, which means there's going to be a discontinuity in such cases. I also think that your question would be more understandable if you included trees illustrating the type of analyses you are considering. Doing so would increase the likelihood of someone producing a coherent answer.

Comment: @TimOsborne Please see the edit.

Comment: Couldn't *first* be a modifier? Is there a relevant structural difference between your sentence and *you are the first to notice the mistake*, and is that sentence a rearrangement of *you noticed the mistake first*?

Answer (score 2):

At the core of the question is a key observation about the nature of certain noun phrases. At times an adjective takes a complement that appears to the right of the noun, which is problematic because the noun intercedes between the two. In other words, a discontinuity (i.e. long-distance dependency) is present inside the noun phrase.

The following pair of sentences illustrate that the adjective is indeed licensing the *to*-phrase:

(1a) You were the first person to notice the mistake.

(1b) ?You were the person to notice the mistake.

Sentence (1b) is odd, although it might work in a context in which others noticed the mistake but those others were not people, but rather, say, aliens. The assumption that the adjective licenses the *to*-phrase is supported by similar data where it is more evident that the adjective is licensing the *to*-phrase, e.g.

(2a)  Jim is a bad person to do it.

(2b) ?Jim is a person to do it.

Sentence (2b) is also odd, which suggests that the adjective *bad* in the a-sentence is licensing the *to*-phrase. More important is the fact that sentence (2a) does not entail that Jim is a bad person; quite to the contrary, he may be a good person, but simply bad for the job at hand.

The question suggests two X-bar theoretic options for the structural analysis. Neither of the suggested options gets the analysis right, though, because neither of them addresses the core problem, this problem being the presence of a discontinuity.

To illustrate this core problem, I now use dependency trees. These trees are simple and easy to produce and hence good for showing what is at stake. The first dependency tree shows that the adjective *first* can indeed be viewed as licensing the *to*-phrase:

[image]

Here we see that when used predicatively, the adjective *first* easily takes the *to*-phrase as its complement dependent. Switching now to the example sentence, a discontinuity is present, as identified by crossing lines:

[image]

The crossing lines identify the discontinuity; in dependency grammar parlance, the crossing lines identify a projectivity violation. The means of rectifying the crossing lines is to assume that extraposition occurs inside the noun phrase. This assumption leads to the following analysis:

[image]

The dashed and dangling dependency edges are conventions used here to indicate the presence of a discontinuity, in this case, an extraposition discontinuity within the noun phrase.

Returning to the two X-bar theoretic analyses suggested in the question, neither of them addresses the presence of a discontinuity. Those two analyses are given next:

[image]

Neither of these structural analyses indicates the presence of a discontinuity, and in this regard, neither of them gets the job done. If forced to choose, however, the second analysis is better insofar as it can be augmented to indicate the presence of a discontinuity, rightward movement of the *to*-phrase out of the AP having occurred.

As a final comment, the author of the question should ponder why the question has gone for days without being answered. My insight in this area is that X-bar theoretic analyses are dense and certainly difficult to produce, demanding more work and analysis than seems worth it in the context of this forum.

Comment: I'm not sure your 1a and 1b are sufficient to show that the to phrase is licensed by the adjective, as e.g. *if there's ever a mistake, you're the one to notice it* is idiomatic for me. I think that the interpretations *you are the first-to-notice-the-mistake person* and *you are the first person who noticed the mistake* are both possible. I suspect you are right that the first of these is the correct parse, but I don't think 1b shows this has to be the case.

Comment: @rchivers I agree that the data behind the argument are not straightforward and that judgements are nuanced. I note that if we have the sentence _You were the one to notice the mistake_, then there's no problem; the sentence is perfectly idiomatic and a standard infinitival relative clause is present that need not be viewed as being licensed by an adjective.

Comment: In *you're the best person to look for mistakes*, it is clear that *to look for mistakes* qualifies *best* and not *person*, because the meaning is the same in *you may be completely depraved, but you're the best person to look for mistakes*. For me the parallel between that construction and the one in the OP is a good indication that, in the original sentence, the infinitival qualifies the adjective, which then qualifies the noun.

Comment: @rchivers Yes, I agree. That is a better example. Thanks. I am going to amend my answer.

Comment: This doesn't really affect your analysis, but (1) and (2) strike me as exemplifying different constructions, for two reasons. First, they differ in meaning -- (1a) entails "you noticed the mistake" and is equivalent to "You are the first person who noticed the mistake", but (2a) does not imply "Jim did it". Second, the construction in (1) requires an adjective that can specifically idenitfy a member of a set (*first, best* etc.), while that in (2) doesn't necessarily require an adjective at all, e.g. *He's the man to do it*.

Comment: Belated thanks for detailed diagrams and explanations. I appreciate your effort. Here are some remarks/questions. 1. It's not clear to me how 'discontinuity' has anything to do with the call of the question. Perhaps because my lack of training in linguistics. 2. You seem to be saying that _to notice the mistake_ is complement of _first person_. Then, how could you choose (5b), where _to notice the mistake_ is an adjunct of _first person_?

Comment: @JK2 In your question, you wrote "...But if it's complement licensed by _first_, which I suspect it is...". I understood that to mean that you (correctly) observed that just _first_ is licensing the appearance of _to notice the mistake_ (not _first person_). The problem, then, is that _first_ is a dependent of _person_ at the same time that _to make the mistake_ is separated from _first_ by _person_. A discontinuity is necessarily present. The crossing lines in (4) show this situation.

Comment: I'll have to think about this more. Thanks!